# Save datatable as user setting

Tags: c#

I currently try to save a datatable as a user setting using die old "properties.settings.default.save()" method.

It does not work. My Settings don't get saved. however it does work when I try to save a string as setting.

So I am really wondering why it doesn't work with the datatable. Saving the datatale would make a lot of things easier for me, so any help on that or any alternative solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You want to save an entire DataTable to an XML file? I am not quite following what you want to do

Comment: Please, can you post your code?

Answer (score 6):

You can save the DataTable as an XML string to an ordinary String setting, like this:

```
 StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
 table.WriteXml(writer);
 Settings.Default.TableXml = writer.ToString();
```

You can then load it from the setting like this:

```
 StringReader reader = new StringReader(Settings.Default.TableXml);
 table.ReadXml(reader);
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe I encountered this same problem while performing a LINQ query on a `DataTable` from an ERP database. After using the `CopyToDataTable()` method on the query result and assigning it to the `settingTable` setting, I verified that neither the `resultTable` nor the `settingTable` were `null` and I ran the `Settings.Default.Save()` method. However, I received a `null` error when I subsequently attempted to assign the `settingTable` to a `dataTable` variable.

I resolved this problem by assigning the `settingTable.TableName` property to something other than its default value (the `null` string) before running the `Settings.Default.Save()` method.

**Note:** The ERP system is really slow, I would just query the data directly using the ERP's business objects.

Answer (score 0):

sadly the solution above doesn't work for me (got an exceptation that the root element is missing). 
I had to make this adjustments.

Create XML String:

```
 StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
 table.WriteXml(writer, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema); //WriteSchema
 Settings.Default.TableXml = writer.ToString();
```

Create DataTable from Xml String

```
 StringReader reader = new StringReader(Settings.Default.TableXml);
 table.ReadXml(reader);
```

Hope this helps al further users having the same problem ;)

Comment: In fact this has nothing to do with the "settings" class. Its just datatable serialization.