# A way to save a specific My.Settings Variable in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, save, my.settings

in My.Settings i've alot of variables including a 36000 records Datatable and Couple Large Array Lists, now when i call My.Settings.Save() it saves all the variables which takes alot of time and it saves variables that haven't been changed, is there a way make it Save only a Specific Datatable or ArrayList?

```
My.Setting.Save() 
'but what i want for example is something like
My.Settings.SomeDatatable.Save()
```

Comment: All of that data is being saved to a single config file, so of course its going to take a while to perform that IO operation.

Comment: is there is a way to make multiple config filses?

Answer (score 0):

These settings are stored in an XML file.  Since XML files do not store data in a fixed-width record format, there is no way to update a single node in an XML file without rewriting the whole thing.  If it is too slow, I would recommend either:

- Store these settings in multiple XML files, so that you only have to save the applicable file, but not the rest
- Store the settings in the database where each row can be saved individually without rewriting the whole file

Databases store their data in fixed-width "pages" so that only the modified pages need to be rewritten, rather than the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

What about saving your **dataTable not within your Settings**. You could make use of [**DataTable.WriteXml()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.writexml.aspx). this would keep your settings much smaller and you can access them separately!

```
' save table
DataTable.WriteXml("yourFile.xml")

' load table
Dim newTable As New DataTable
newTable.ReadXml(fileName)
```

But if there is no other possibility [**this solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295348/save-datatable-as-user-setting) from [*SLaks*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks) will work too

```
' save table
Dim writer As New StringWriter()
table.WriteXml(writer)
My.MySettings.Default.TableXml = writer.ToString()

' load table
Dim reader As New StringReader(My.MySettings.Default.TableXml)
table.ReadXml(reader)
```